# I'm trying to move an arm back and forth, but it doesn't work

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to move an R6 model's arm back and forth. It does not work but does not give an error.

```
local R6 = script.Parent
local animate = R6["Left Arm"]
local x = animate.Position.X
local y = animate.Position.Y
local z = animate.Position.Z
local newPos = Vector3.new(x, y, z + 1)
local oldPos = Vector3.new(x, y, z)
while true do
    wait(1)
    animate.Position = newPos
    wait(1)
    animate.Position = oldPos
end
```